# this error in android studio while developing flutter android app

Tags: android, flutter, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradlew

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'G:\Flutter Apps\hehe\android\build.gradle' line: 26
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.

> Build completed with 1 failures.
> org/jetbrains/kotlin/build/report/metrics/BuildTime

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

I tried checking plugin update changing kotlin version in build.gradle file in android studio. I followed all Videos and tutorial to download and install flutter and start making android apps.